# Convert []int to []string in golang in one line

Tags: string, go, slice

I'm a beginner with Go. Converting a slice of ints to a slice of strings seems simple with a few lines:

```
nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
sNums := make([]string, len(nums))
for i, x := range nums {
    sNums[i] = strconv.Itoa(x)
}
```

However, I am wondering if there is a way to do it using a quick one-liner using built-ins/standard library, similar to the following in Python:

```
sNums = map(str, nums)
```

Comment: That's the shortest code using functions available in the standard library.

Comment: Go doesn't like "quick one-liners". Go takes the approach to never hide complexity, so an explicit for loop is the correct approach in Go.

Comment: you could wrap that code in a func and then call it as a one-liner.  Funcs are cheap in Go

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for a `map` function that operates on slices. That would require generics and as of Go 1.11, generics are not yet supported. The standard library also doesn't provide a built-in function for these types of operations (map, filter, reduce, etc).

What you already have is quite enough for this simple use case. Wrap it in a function and that would fit your need. Until Go supports generics, you have to hand write operations on each type of slice.

Some links for reading:

[Generics Proposal](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-generics-overview.md)

[Rob Pike's Filter Library](https://github.com/robpike/filter)

Answer (score 1):

What you want *can* be done with a single line, but those solutions are inferior (in performance) to the simple loop you presented in the question. So here come some one-liners, but I would probably never use them to achieve what you want, so just use a `for` loop, and if you have to do this many times, create a helper function (that will use the loop), and just call the helper function.

The following one-liners all build on the [`fmt.Sprint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprint) function, which generates a string representation for `int` slices like this (without the quotes):

```
"[e1 e2 e3...]"
```

Where `e1`, `e2`... are the elements of the input slice.

So for example:

```
nums := []int{1, 2, -3, 4}
s := fmt.Sprint(nums)
fmt.Printf("%q", s)
```

Will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/i_9JhLtFFmH)):

```
"[1 2 -3 4]"
```

We may "transform" this single `string` value to its elements using 2 steps:

1. Get rid of the leading and trailing square brackets
2. Split (break) the remaining text on spaces

And we're done.

For the first step, we have several options, e.g. [`strings.Replace()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace), [`strings.Replacer`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replacer), [`strings.Trim()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Trim). We may "spice" up the trimming by slicing the string, to cut its first character (e.g. `s[1:]`) so then it will be only needed to remove the trailing `']'`.

For the second step, we have [`strings.Split()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split).

Without all the possible combinations, here are 3 one-liner examples to convert an `int` slice to a `string` slice:

```
nums := []int{1, 2, -3, 4}

sNums := strings.Split(strings.Replace(fmt.Sprint(nums)[1:], "]", "", -1), " ")
fmt.Printf("%q\n", sNums)

sNums2 := strings.Split(strings.Trim(fmt.Sprint(nums), "[]"), " ")
fmt.Printf("%q\n", sNums2)

sNums3 := strings.Split(strings.TrimRight(fmt.Sprint(nums)[1:], "]"), " ")
fmt.Printf("%q\n", sNums3)
```

Output of the above (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4JDvuIU1uuh)):

```
["1" "2" "-3" "4"]
["1" "2" "-3" "4"]
["1" "2" "-3" "4"]
```

There is one edge case that none of the above solutions handle: if the input is an empty slice, the output will be a slice containing an empty string (when it should be an empty slice). The reason for this is because if the input does not contain the space separator (in this case it's the empty string), `strings.Split()` returns the input (which will be the empty string).

To handle the empty-input-slice edge case, we may use the [`strings.SplitN()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#SplitN) function instead of `strings.Split()`, passing `len(nums)` as the max number of parts we want. So if the input slice is empty, the output slice will also be empty:

```
nums := []int{}

sNums := strings.SplitN(strings.Replace(fmt.Sprint(nums)[1:], "]", "", -1), " ", len(nums))
fmt.Printf("%q\n", sNums)

sNums2 := strings.SplitN(strings.Trim(fmt.Sprint(nums), "[]"), " ", len(nums))
fmt.Printf("%q\n", sNums2)

sNums3 := strings.SplitN(strings.TrimRight(fmt.Sprint(nums)[1:], "]"), " ", len(nums))
fmt.Printf("%q\n", sNums3)
```

This will properly output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/acrK3HbjQju)):

```
[]
[]
[]
```

One thing to note here: the presented solutions are kind of like generic, because the solutions work with other types of slices, e.g. `[]int8`, `[]int32`, `[]float32` etc., even with arrays, e.g. `[4]int`...